# Cannot find Java package powermock.api.mockito

Tags: java, maven, powermock

I am trying to get Power Mockito to work in my java test. For the life of me I cannot get it to find it. I tried inserting the dependency in the pom file, rebuild project and run the tests, but it still will not find it. Any ideas why it will not find this?

Here's what I have in my `MemberServiceTest.java` file:

```
package com.cerner.revenuecycle.vbr.services;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito; //***** cant find *****
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest; //**** cant find ****
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner; //***** cant find ****

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MemberServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MemberService memberService;

    @Mock
    MemberHibernate memberHibernate;

    @Mock
    CaseHelper caseHelper;

    @Test
    public void testGetCaseNumber() {

        SessionFactory testSessionFactory = HibernateUtil.newTestSessionFactory();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(HibernateUtil.class); //this doesnt work now


        PowerMockito.when(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()).thenReturn(testSessionFactory); //this doesnt work now 
        Case case1 = new Case();
        Case case2 = new Case();
        case1.setTenantId("1");
        case2.setTenantId("2");

        String caseNum1 = caseHelper.getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(case1.getTenantId());
        String caseNum2 = caseHelper.getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(case2.getTenantId());

        assertEquals(caseNum1, caseNum2);

    }
}
```

and in my `pom.xml` file, as you can see I've put the mockito and powermock dependencies in there:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cerner.revenuecycle.vbr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vbr-services-integration</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.cerner.revenuecycle.vbr</groupId>
        <artifactId>vbr-services-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <name>vbr-services-integration</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any idea why it is not finding the library for powermockito?

Comment: I just run your example (with removed dependencies to your classes) and it went without any errors. Could you add some more details what are the symptoms of `//***** cant find *****` is it your IDE complaining about missing dependencies or are you getting errors during maven run.

Comment: Why are you using the old version. Found a thread which kind of suggests that you should use power-mock 1.6.2 for jUnit 4.4+
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have tryed that but here go.

Try to force the update of the dependences "mvn clean install -U", and also try to check if the jar is in your m2. folder

Comment: Just ran that and it said: cannot find symbol                                               [INFO] 5 errors 
                                     [INFO] vbr-services-integration ........................... SKIPPED

[ERROR] symbol:   variable PowerMockito

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle:

```
    // required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
    // required if you want to use Mockito for Android tests
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'
```